# R Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newCol", value = "categories") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to categorize messy data with a dataframe with four columns:

1. "company_name", which is the messy data I want to categorize
2. "categories", which are the categories I want to put the messy data in
3. "search", which are the keywords I want to search in the messy data
4. "company_type", which will have the correct company type for each row

> ```
>  "company_name"           "categories"      "search"    "company_type"
>    John landscaping        Landscaping       lawn          NA
>    Brother Lawn care       Cleaning          clean         NA
>     Top cleaning           Painting          paint         NA
> ```

I want my final result to look like this:

> ```
>  "company_name"           "categories"      "search"    "company_type"
>    John landscaping        Landscaping       lawn          Landscaping 
>    Brother Lawn care       Cleaning          clean         Landscaping 
>     Top cleaning           Painting          paint         Cleaning
> ```

I am using the function created by Chris Leonard here: https://r-dir.com/blog/2015/01/quickly-categorize-messy-data.html

And this is the code

```
df$company_type <- NA
  
categorizeDF <- function(df, searchColName, searchList, catList, newColName="Category") {
  catDF <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(df), nrow=0))
  colnames(catDF) <- paste0(names(df))
  df$sequence <- seq(nrow(df))
  for (i in seq_along(searchList)) {
    rownames(df) <- NULL
    index <- grep(searchList[i], df[,which(colnames(df) == searchColName)], ignore.case=TRUE)
    tempDF <- df[index,]
    tempDF$newCol <- catList[i]
    catDF <- rbind(catDF, tempDF)
    df <- df[-index,]
  }
  if (nrow(df) > 0) {
    df$newCol <- "OTHER"
    catDF <- rbind(catDF, df)
  }
  catDF <- catDF[order(catDF$sequence),]
  catDF$sequence <- NULL
  rownames(catDF) <- NULL
  catDF$newCol <- as.factor(catDF$newCol)
  colnames(catDF)[which(colnames(catDF) == "newCol")] <- newColName
  catDF
}

sorted <- categorizeDF(df, "company_name", "search", "categories", "company_type")
```

however, I'm getting an error (with trace back):

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newCol", value = "categories") : 
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
4.
stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
"replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
3.
`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newCol", value = "categories")
2.
`$<-`(`*tmp*`, "newCol", value = "categories")
1.
categorizeDF(df, "company_name", "search", "categories", "company_type")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the search strings not in any of the messy data column

updated and it worked:

```
categorizeDF <- function(df, searchColName, searchList, catList, newColName="Category") {
  catDF <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(df), nrow=0))
  colnames(catDF) <- paste0(names(df))
  df$sequence <- seq(nrow(df))
  for (i in seq_along(searchList)) {
    rownames(df) <- NULL
    index <- grep(searchList[i], df[,which(colnames(df) == searchColName)], ignore.case=TRUE)
   
     if (identical(index,integer(0))){
      next
     }
    
    tempDF <- df[index,]
    tempDF$newCol <- catList[i]
    catDF <- rbind(catDF, tempDF)
    df <- df[-index,]
  }
  if (nrow(df) > 0) {
    df$newCol <- "OTHER"
    catDF <- rbind(catDF, df)
  }
  catDF <- catDF[order(catDF$sequence),]
  catDF$sequence <- NULL
  rownames(catDF) <- NULL
  catDF$newCol <- as.factor(catDF$newCol)
  colnames(catDF)[which(colnames(catDF) == "newCol")] <- newColName
  catDF
}
```